# twitteR package: how to get users informations from an id's followers list

Tags: r, twitter

Using twitteR package: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/twitteR/twitteR.pdf

Connecting to twitter API:

```
library (twitteR)
consumer_key <- "xxxx"
consumer_secret <- "xxxx"
access_token <- "xxxx"
access_secret <- "xxxx"
setup_twitter_oauth(consumer_key, consumer_secret, access_token, access_secret)
```

Getting a collection of 10 relevant tweets matching #nantes query:

```
nantes_tag <- searchTwitter("#nantes", n =10)
nantes_tag <- twListToDF(nantes_tag) # converting to df
```

Extracting id's vector from my data.frame object:

```
user_id <- nantes_tag$id
```

A short output:

```
user_id <- c("800684281337147392", 
             "800684281295212544",
             "800684084687228928",
             " 800684024406609923", 
             "800683967884050432")
```

How can I get user's information for each id using `getuser()` function and store them in a data.frame object?

I tried without success:

```
users <- lookupUsers(user_id)
```

Can I make a loop over `user_id` with `get_user()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using the `Id`'s , I would suggest you to use the `screen names` of the users

```
usernames <- nantes_tag$screenName
```

and then pass character vector of these screen names to `lookupUsers` and then wrap it around `twListToDF` to get the required output in dataframe format.

```
temp_df <- twListToDF(lookupUsers(usernames))
```